# Is there any way to execute steps in an orderly manner by release on Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I used to work with Azure DevOps on CI/CD with its release pipelines. We are a multidisciplinary team, however we do implement features on same projects simultaneously. On good old release pipelines the steps run on a FIFO style. For instance, if I trigger release X and a colleague triggers release Y right after, he would never run Production step at the same time that me, release Y would be blocked on Production step until X is finished on Production step.

It turns out that we've moved to Azure pipelines as code and we faced this issue. Releases does not work on FIFO style anymore on its steps, which would cause a "race condition" with releases.

Is there a way to emulate old Release pipeline behaviour? Thanks on advance.

[Current pipeline and expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqCJo.png)

Comment: Are these individual builds of the same pipeline, or two different pipelines?

Comment: Hi MeloFelipe, How about this issue, you could try it and then kindly share the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each release will start from stage 1. Thus we can add a PowerShell task as the first task for stage 1 to check if there are previous in-progress deployments.

In this PowerShell task, we can call this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to check release stage status.

Power shell script:

```
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
    $token = "$(pat)"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $success = $false
    $count = 0
do{
    try{
    $stageurl2 = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId={release definition ID}&deploymentStatus=inProgress&api-version=6.0"
    $stageinfo2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $stageurl2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
   
    $inprogressdeployments = $stageinfo2.value | where {($_.deploymentStatus -eq "inProgress")  -and ($_.release.name -ne $ENV:RELEASE_RELEASENAME)  -and ($_.releaseEnvironment.name -ne 'stop services')} | Sort-Object -Property completedOn -Descending
    #write-output $inprogressdeployments
    $stageurl3 = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId={release definition ID}&operationStatus=QueuedForAgent&api-version=6.0"
    $stageinfo3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $stageurl3 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    $queueddeployments = $stageinfo3.value
    #write-output $queueddeployments
        if($inprogressdeployments) {            
            Write-output "Deployment In Progress, Waiting for it to finish!"  
            Write-output "Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30          
      } else {            
            Write-Host "No Current Deployment in Progress"
            if($queueddeployments) {
            write-output "Current Queued deployments"
            Write-output "if 2 - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30 
            }
            else{
            write-output "No Queued deployments, starting release"
            $success = $true      
            }      
      }
    }
    catch{
        Write-output "catch - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
        write-output "1"
        Start-sleep -Seconds 30
      # Put the start-sleep in the catch statemtnt so we
      # don't sleep if the condition is true and waste time
    }
    
    $count++
    
}until($count -eq 2000 -or $success)
if(-not($success)){exit}
```

Result:

Stage1 will continue to check until all previous versions are complete

[image]

In addition, you need purchase parallel jobs or create multiple self-hosted agent

Another solution is set exclusive lock, you could refer to this [Exclusive deployment lock policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#exclusive-deployment-lock-policy) and [Evaluate artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#evaluate-artifact) for more details.